# работа с несколькими моделями yii2

Tags: yii2

как реализовать работу actionUpdate[image: вот actionCreate]

а вот код из  actionUpdate

```
public function actionUpdate($id)[![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $performer = $this->findModel($id);

            if(!isset($model,$performer)){
                throw new NotFoundHttpException("The user was not found.");     
            }
            $model->scenario = 'update';
            $performer->scenario = 'update';
            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $performer->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
            {

              $isValid = $model->validate();
              $isValid = $performer->validate() && $isValid;
              if($isValid){
                  $model->save(false);
                  $performer->save(false);

                //  $performer->id_task = $model->id;
                //  $performer->save();
                  return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
      // } else{

              }
            }

            return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
            'performer' => $performer,
            ]);
        }
```

Comment: Undefined variable: performer                                                                                                                 <?= $form->field($performer, 'id_user')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Users::find()->all(),'id','username')) ?> ошибка, ругается на views/tasks/form

Comment: Потому что и модель, и перформер получены из одного метода $this->findModel($id);